# How to dynamically set control IDs inside a repeater template?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Here is a perplexing issue I have not seen a good answer to on StackOverflow, although there a couple stabs at it...  I have a situation where I'd like to do this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="MyRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li id="id?">
            All the other stuff
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The question... is how do I get the ID of my <li> elements to be id1, id2, id3, etc., based on the ItemIndex they are bound to?  So far the most... er..."elegant" solution I've come up with is to replace the <li> with an asp:Literal and dump the <li...>' text.  But that just feels... so wrong.  And no, I'm not using ASP.NET 4.0, which I've read will provide this functionality.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="MyRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li id="li<%# ((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex + 1%>">
            All the other stuff
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Ommiting the cast and just using `Container.ItemIndex` is sufficient.

Comment: What if i want to put like this  <%# (Container.ItemIndex+4) % 4 == 0 ? "<div id='Row_<%# ((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex + 1%>' class='clearbth amc_row'>" : "" %> ?

Comment: Thanks, this saved me